# How to use a variable with multiple values for different environments (Test,Prod & QA) in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, configuration, web-config, jenkins-plugins, devops

[image]

I want to use a variable with multiple values for different environments(Test, prod & QA). For example i have a variable DB_Name with values DB_Test, DB_Prod and DB_QA in jenkins UI with another variable of scope which has value Test,QA and Prod so when i build pipeline with Test so jenkins should pick up all the variable of scope=Test and replace them in a json file in jenkins (As shown in picture). This functionality is available in octopus deploy but i want to do it in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at parametrized configuration in Jenkins job...